# Encapsulating server communication for data intensive multi-server applications

Tags: database, performance, webserver, encapsulation, bigdata

There are two databases, A and B, that serve web pages and communicate with each-other via internal network when they need to share data.  Sometimes server A needs to produce a webpage with a chart that requires intensive calculations involving a large quantity of data on server B.  Lets assume both servers are equally powerful and the network is fast.  I'm trying to figure out a good way to do this.  Ideas so far:

- Server B could do a lot of the calculations then pass back a small set of results to server A.  Less flexible, but fairly efficient.  Unfortunately this is a somewhat complex transaction.  I'd compare it to a method with a lot of parameters, side-effects and results.
- Server B could simply provide its own raw data server to A and let it handle all of the calculations itself.  More "open" and flexible, but less efficient since there is a lot of data involved in the calculation, and server A would have to pull all of it over the network.
- Server B could produce and return the chart, or a link to it.  Perhaps the most efficient, but least flexible, and also creates a messy relationship where server B is partially responsible for producing server A's webpages.  However, at least server A doesn't have to worry about getting back a complex object and know what to do with it.

Is there a best practice here that results in a balance of performance and maintainable encapsulation?  Or is it simply a case-by-case situation?  I'm leaning towards the first option.  I hope this question is "answerable" enough and not a discussion issue.  I've tried to concentrate the general problem into a specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer the best practice part of your question, But will for the performance aspect. What you have described is two servers with no real technical difference between them, and presumably you have equal access to update both of them, neither starved of resource, etc.

To truly calculate performance, there are a few number needed.

A) how many requests per second?
B) for techniques a and b, how much traffic will flow between the machines?
C) how much latency can you withstand?

Your first option will be reasonable for performance, if the data flowing is small enough. Option b will generate most load on your infra structure, and if this is approaching hardware limits then ditch this option now. If all the numbers are small, then this isn't really a performance based decision.

If you are driving this all from web pages, then cannot the first page load simply return Img tags etc that refer to server B? Ie I request pageA, but the HTML stream includes resources from serverB? This is essentially your option C, but will perhaps give higher perceived user performance as the resources from different servers can download in parallel (assuming there are several to be accessed).

from a design standpoint, I struggle to see *Where* a calculation is performed is Relevant in this question, you control both servers, so the question becomes what 'contract' does server b have to provide information to server a.  Is there some reason that b cannot provide filtered results only and never the underlying raw data? Or put another way, why should a have to process b's data? Whether the logic is in a or b doesn't matter when you control both ends.

If you do not control both servers, then the decision is more around who should bare the cost (build and support) for processing the raw data to results.

Summary/opinion. Option c if possible and suitable, else a in absence of some overriding reason for b